# Sampling Theorem for band limited continuous spectrum signal

Tags: sampling

For example a signal $y(t)$ contains infinite number of sine waves each with varying finite random amplitudes and random frequencies between $-B$ to $B$. Can this signal be reconstructed when sampling at the Nyquist-Shannon sampling rate?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are describing classical Nyquistian sampling for a complex spectrum that can be recreated if you do complex sampling at >2B?

Comment: The signals are real.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not, but it depends on the details

1. If you have an infinite number of sine wave, each with a finite amplitude, than the signal itself will be infinite as well.
2. If "varying amplitude" means that the amplitude varies over time, than the sine waves are not sine waves any more. Whether this is bandlimited or not, depends on the nature on how exactly the amplitude varies

Comment: What if the amplitudes are scaled such that the signal is not infinite?

Comment: You can't. Not if the number of sine waves is infinite.

Comment: @Hilmar, an infinite sum of finite values can converge. Even if all summed values are positive. Since the OP has not said anything about the phase relationship between the sines, it's not particularly hard to think of a probability distribution for the amplitudes that would result in a finitely bounded sum.

Answer (score 0):

There is no particular reason, according to my understanding of your question, that the original bandlimited signal can't be reconstructed from its Nyquist rate samples.
But bandlimited signals have an infinite presence in the time domain. Meaning, your samples should span the whole range of time-domain and not a finite duration of time, which is practically infeasible.